# DRY-ing up some Rspecs which perform very similar operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have several tests within one spec file which looks very similar to this (This is in a describe block):

```
let(:helpful_variable1) {Helpful.new}
let(:helpful_variable2) {Helpful2.new}

before(:all) do
    login_and_authenticate
end

it 'should do x' do
    do_this
    do_that

    do_x
    validate_x
end

it 'should do y' do
    do_this
    do_that

    do_x
    do_y
    validate_x
    validate_y
end

it 'should do x twice' do
    do_this
    do_that

    do_x_twice
    validate_x_was_done_twice
end
```

Obviously this is highly abstracted, but the actual file looks very similar to this in terms of the structure and function calls. There is a lot of code repetition here, but I can't seem to figure out what the best way of DRY-ing it is. Important to note that:

1. First test does X
2. Second test does X AND Y
3. Third test does X twice (but it has to be run in a different test and run like this because what is tested

I thought about using shared_example or shared_context but I'm not as knowledgeable about it and from examples I've seen online, however I can't seem to grasp if it can help me here or not.

Surely there is a more elegant way of writing it, though I'm not sure how.
Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: For starters, it looks like you can `do_this` and `do_that` in a `before` block. Hard to say otherwise without seeing the actual code. Is there a reason you can't post the code?

Comment: OK So I tried that but it's a bit of an issue because those methods use the variables declared in "let", so when I ran the tests it threw me an error. I instead changed the "let" to be instance variables but that didn't work either, it failed on something which I can't recall. I can't post the code since it's actual production code. I did try to make it as close to the original as possible though

Comment: @user475680 can you show the attempt using instance variables and `before(:each)` block? You can change your top-secret variable names to aliases, no snitches here.

Comment: Another point is to use `context/describe` to wrap `it`-s for better specification output and code structure. You'll be able to place preparation code inside `before` (same as `before(:each)`) blocks, to make sure, that it will be executed only for nested cases.

Comment: I really can't answer this question properly without seeing a more complete code example. Based on the limited, abstract information you've given, all I can really say is: Put `do_this` and `do_that` in a `before` block; make `do_x`, `do_y`, etc into methods. Sorry, but I'm voting to close this on the grounds of it being too broad -- there are many possible approaches, but not enough concrete information to suggest anything..

Comment: If you have a bug - we can't help unless you give us something more concrete to work with... It's unlikely your production code does anything proprietary, then changing the variable names will totally be sufficient that we won't know what you're doing... and really unless you're sharing the internals of google's algorithm you're probably not doing much we haven't seen before ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case for contexts and before blocks. eg:

```
let(:helpful_variable1) {Helpful.new}
let(:helpful_variable2) {Helpful2.new}

before(:all) do
  login_and_authenticate
end

context "when this and that" do
  begin do
    do_this
    do_that
  end

  it 'should do x' do    
    do_x
    validate_x
  end

  it 'should do y' do
    do_x
    do_y
    validate_x
    validate_y
  end

  it 'should do x twice' do
    do_x_twice
    validate_x_was_done_twice
  end
end
```

Now, contexts can also be nested.
I don't know what you're trying to do with `do_x`, it might be an assertion... but assuming it's another setup-thing, you could also nest it for the relevant specs (and not the other ones)... eg

```
let(:helpful_variable1) {Helpful.new}
let(:helpful_variable2) {Helpful2.new}

before(:all) do
  login_and_authenticate
end

context "when this and that" do
  begin do
    do_this
    do_that
  end

  context "and also X is done" do
    before do
      do_x
    end

    it 'validates x' do    
      validate_x
    end

    context 'twice...' do
      before do
        do_x # again
      end

      it 'validates x was done twice' do
        validate_x_was_done_twice
      end
    end

    context "and y is done" do
      before do
        do_y
      end

      it 'validates x and y' do
        validate_x
        validate_y
      end
    end
  end
end
```